# Rails 4 - Dynamic Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app where users can define their own "statuses".  I then create a dynamic scope to handle this.  This is working perfectly fine locally, but when I push to Heroku it is not for some reason.

Model: Task.rb:

```
  Status.all.each do |status|
    scope "#{status.name}".downcase.delete(' '), -> { where('status_id = ?', status.id).order('created_at DESC') }
  end
```

Route: routes.rb:

```
get 'tasks/filters/status/:scope' => "tasks#index"
```

Controller: tasks_controller.rb:

In the case that the user clicks on the status from the view, it falls into the `else` block and runs the `if params[:scope]` part and executes `@tasks = Task.send(params[:scope])`:

```
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all.order('name')
    if params[:tag]
      @tasks = Task.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      if params[:scope]
        @tasks = Task.send(params[:scope])
      elsif params[:showall]
        @tasks = Task.all.order('created_at DESC')
      else
        @tasks = Task.all.where('assigned_to = ?', current_user).order('created_at DESC').
          reject { |t| t.status.default_view != true }
      end
    end
  end
```

As I said, this works perfectly when I run locally using `rails s`, but when I push to Heroku, I get an error.  Running `heroku logs` reveals this:

```
2015-06-17T15:06:07.769748+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"scope"=>"open"}
2015-06-17T15:06:07.895996+00:00 app[web.1]:   Role Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "public"."roles".* FROM "public"."roles" WHERE "public"."roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-06-17T15:06:07.907046+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)):
2015-06-17T15:06:07.907043+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-17T15:06:07.907050+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-17T15:06:07.907048+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:12:in `index'
2015-06-17T15:06:07.907049+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-17T15:06:07.972702+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/tasks/filters/status/open" for 173.27.229.45 at 2015-06-17 15:06:07 +0000
2015-06-17T15:06:07.998359+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms
```

Where line 12 in tasks_controller.rb is:

```
@tasks = Task.send(params[:scope])
```

What gives?  It says `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+))`, but the first entry clearly shows that the parameter "scope" is being set properly (in this case to "open").

Comment: I don't think passing `params[:scope]` to `Task.send` is such a great idea. What happens if someone sets `scope` to `destroy_all` or something else destructive?

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal - Good catch!  I did not consider that.  Looks like I will have to think of another way to support this feature.

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal - or maybe just restrict the user from creating anything that is a method or instance_method of Task?  Is that still bad?

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure why it worked in development, but not production, as @PerfectlyNormal pointed out, the way I was doing it was a security risk.

I think I over-thought how to do this a bit.  I came up with this way and it appears to be working fine:

```
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all.order('name')
    @priorities = Priority.all.order('name')
    @products = Product.all.order('name')
    if params[:status_id]
      @tasks = Task.all.where("status_id = ?", params[:status_id])
    elsif params[:priority_id]
      @tasks = Task.all.where("priority_id = ?", params[:priority_id])
    elsif params[:product_id]
      @tasks = Task.all.where("product_id = ?", params[:product_id])
    elsif params[:tag]
      @tasks = Task.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    elsif params[:all_tasks]
      @tasks = Task.all
    else
      @tasks = Task.all
    end
  end
```

Then in my view (which uses a simple helper I wrote to display it as a Bootstrap 3 label depending on a color the user chose):

```
          <% @statuses.all.each do |status| %>
            <%= link_to "/tasks/filters/status/#{status.id}" do %>
              <%= filter_status(status) %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

And finally in my `routes.rb`:

```
get 'tasks/filters/status/:status_id' => "tasks#index"
get 'tasks/filters/priority/:priority_id' => "tasks#index"
get 'tasks/filters/product/:product_id' => "tasks#index"
```